# Custom Attribute Display Pop-up (hyperlink converting "/' to "%2F")

Tags: attribute-table, popup, feature-service, url, arcgis-online-webmap

I have created a custom attribute display links in an ArcGIS Online webmap that include a field from my ArcGIS Server Feature Service attribute table (using attribute-based URL parameters). I am having an issue where the "/" in my attribute field record is appearing as "%2F" in the hyperlink and thus the proper URL is not opening.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS, and the attribute table in question is within an ArcGIS Server Feature Service (published from ArcGIS).